# reciving json from rabbitmq in groovy

Tags: json, groovy, rabbitmq

I have problem with parsing json provided by RabbitMq.
When I print Rabbit message i got:

```
{id=546456, userId=345345}
```

I need to parse this json with JsonSlurper but i got exception:

```
groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to parse JSON object



     The current character read is '{' with an int value of 123
    expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'i' with an int value of 105
    line number 1
    index number 1
```

It seems that quotes chars are missing. How to parse it without errors? Thanks

edit

When i send this message:

```
{'id':663558460,"userId":345345}
```

I recive this message in same form eg:

```
{'id':663558460,"userId":345345}
```

But there is another exception:

```
The current character read is ''' with an int value of 39
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char ''' with an int value of 39
line number 1
index number 1
```

Comment: So basically, this is not JSON you're dealing with. What is it? Does the sender have a parser they can provide you for this format?

Comment: I'm sending valid json: {"id":663558460,"userId":345345} (even from rabbit web manager).

Comment: This comment contradicts the question where single quotes around `id` are shown.

Answer (score 3):

this is not valid JSON: `{id=546456, userId=345345}`

neither is this: `{'id':663558460,"userId":345345}`

the JSON spec requires double-quotes for keys and string values.

this is valid JSON: `{"id":663558460,"userId":345345}`

note the double quotes around both keys. You need to adjust your code to send your JSON documents properly formatted

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) (the JSON Query processor) can be helpful with quasi-JSON input.  In the particular case you give, if the quasi-JSON text is put in a file named invalid.json:

```
$ jq -n -f <(sed 's/=/:/g' invalid.json)
{
  "id": 546456,
  "userId": 345345
}
```

The above only works because in your case, substituting ":" for "=" blindly is satisfactory.

Even if that is not the case, however, chances are that the combination of jq and some "text-wrangling" will do the job.